# Python - Remove axis tick labels, keeping ticks and axis label

Tags: python, axis-labels

I would like to remove the numerical values in each thick of my y-axis (10, 20, 30, etc.) but keeping the thick marks and the axis label.
So far I just have:

```
yticks([])
```

but it removes the ticks as well. I also tried:

```
frame=gca()
frame.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
```

but it removes both axis label and axis ticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the tick labels to an empty list:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
gca().set_xticklabels(['']*10)
plot(range(10))
```

Results in
[image]

I had to do that before I called `plot`. Not sure why the other way around didn't work

Comment: The problem is that this removes the tick marks over the axis. I want to keep the marks but not the values on the side.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Mathieu that tick_params() is a better method (because you don't need to know the number of ticks in advance), however the most generalized parameter is "label1On," i.e.:

`gca().tick_params(axis='x',label1On=False)`

This approach easily extends to 'y' axis, as well as the second 'x' or 'y' axes (using label2On).

Answer (score 2):

The `tick_params()` function should do the job:

```
gca().tick_params(axis='x',labelbottom='off')
```