# Removing all but one tick on x-axis

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, label

I have a graph that I would tick to remove all ticks and their corresponding labels bar the first tick and label on the x-axis. How would I go about this?

```
import pylab 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


a=np.linspace(0,10,10000)
print a

def f(x):
    return 1/(1-(x**2)*np.log((1/(x**2)+1)))

b=f(a)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)


ax.plot(b,a)

pylab.xlim(0.5, 5)
pylab.ylim(0, 1.5)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to ask - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. What have you tried so far? have you searched stack overflow and looked at elements in answers like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30370038/remove-tick-labels-in-python-but-keep-gridlines) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520244/python-remove-axis-tick-labels-keeping-ticks-and-axis-label?rq=1) ?

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a rough sketch of what it is you're after?

Comment: I would only like 1 tick and its label on the graph at the point (1,0)

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`ax.set_xticks([1])`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks) to set just one `xtick` at 1,0.

Also, there's no need to import both `pylab` and `matplotlib.pyplot`. [The recommended way](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pyplot-and-pylab-how-are-they-related) now is to import `matplotlib.pyplot` and use all the `Axes` methods. E.g., you can use [`ax.set_xlim`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim) instead of `pylab.xlim`.

Here's your full script and output plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


a=np.linspace(0,10,10000)
print a

def f(x):
    return 1/(1-(x**2)*np.log((1/(x**2)+1)))

b=f(a)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

ax.plot(b,a)

ax.set_xlim(0.5, 5)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1.5)

ax.set_xticks([1])

plt.show()
```

[image]